# Connection refused when using cross origin

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-boot

[image]I am using from Angular and spring-boot.
When I want to call api outside the localhost
I am giving me a connection refused error.

Angular service:

```
export class ProfileService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8090/users';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getProfile(id: number): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}` + '/load/' + `${id}`);
  }
```

spring-boot Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
 }
```

userscontroller that get request from angular  :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {
    @Autowired
    private IUsersService iUsersService;

    @GetMapping("/list/grid")
    public Iterable<UsersViewModel> getAllEmployees() {
        return Dozer.mapList(iUsersService.getAll(), UsersViewModel.class);
    }

    @GetMapping("/load/{id}")
    public UsersViewModel getUserById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long userId){
        return Dozer.mapClass(iUsersService.findById(userId).get(),UsersViewModel.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if [this1](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) helps.

Comment: My code like this . it's true for localhost but out side it is wrong

Comment: Are you using Spring Security ?, in that case, please include your Spring Security Configuration in your question

Comment: no i don't use from it

Comment: Please specify what Spring boot version are you using ? and also that you aren't using Spring Boot in your question, because there are different approaches to setup CORS depending on it.

Comment: I use from version 2.1.5.RELEASE spring boot

Comment: Can you clarify these questions
1) Is your spring boot application running on 8090
2) If not does the application on that port allowing cross origin?

Comment: My spring-boot running on port 8090 but this port is not open and it uses in localhost

Answer (score 0):

Please change this to `config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"));`

to

`config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));`

Answer (score -1):

Remove the setAllowedOrigins method and try again. Setting and empty list may be you are banning all requests out of your server

Comment: i did this but error for Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Comment: When call api outside the localhost form angular, angular has configured the correct url rather than localhost?

Comment: What is this ? Please explain.

Comment: I asked if the url (host and port) of the Angular Service is correct. If were localhost and execute angular service outside the host when webapp is deployed could be a reason because you got the connection refused error.